# Combining CGContext Geometry

Tags: cgcontext, cgpath

Does anyone know if it is possible to combine (for example) different CGContext paths to create a new combined shape as in this example?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a library that does Union operations on CGPaths:

https://bitbucket.org/martinwinter/vectorbooleancg

I haven't tried it yet, but the author of the CG branch of Vectorbool, Martin Winter, states that the union operation should be usable in its current form on iOS. I will add information when I get around to trying to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is an Apple lib that supports this feature.

What you need is a so called "union of two (or more) polygons", sometimes called boolean operations on polygons.
I would convert the CGPath to a polygon, probably you start creating a point array that contains your polygon points. That means to not use CGPathAddEllipse, but to approximate the shapes , by e.g a regular polygon with something between 64 and 256 vertices.

You can easily calculate the points of a circle or ellipse for yourself (using something similar to a*cos(t), b*sin(t) see wikipedia for ellipse "parameter formula")
Then you take one of the c libraries that provide these "union operation".
One of that is the LEDA lib.

Comment: Thanks AlexWien, but I actually need Bezier curves, not polygons.